# Find a (simple?) counterexample to this statement about topological manifolds.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let us assume by a topological manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ I mean a Hausdorff topological space that is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^n$, where $n$ is fixed.

I know that if $M$ is assumed separable and paracompact, then $M$ admits an exhaustion by compact sets.

Is this still true if $M$ is only assumed separable, and not necessarily paracompact?

Thanks.

Comment: Silly question: why are separable manifolds not automatically second-countable? (That is to say, what's a counterexample?)

Comment: @Mike: According to [this MathOverflow answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/211959), there are even non-normal separable complex manifolds; it gives a reference. And M. E. Rudin and P. Zenor, *A perfectly normal non­-metrizable manifold*, Houston.J. Math. $2$ ($1976$), $129­$-$134$, constructs a perfectly normal, hereditarily separable, non-metrizable manifold assuming $\mathsf{CH}$. These, being non-metrizable, cannot be second countable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks for the reference!

Comment: I think the Prüfer manifold is also an example. But it's not even normal, so weaker than the other example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/211959), there are even non-normal separable complex manifolds; it gives a reference, and a comment below it notes that the version of the Prüfer surface mentioned in the cited reference is also separable and non-normal. And M. E. Rudin and P. Zenor, *A perfectly normal non­-metrizable manifold*, Houston.J. Math. $2$ ($1976$), $129­$-$134$, constructs a perfectly normal, hereditarily separable, non-metrizable manifold assuming $\mathsf{CH}$. If any of these admitted an exhaustion by compact sets, it would be second countable: each compact set is covered by finitely many charts, and each chart is second countable. But then it would be metrizable by the Uryson metrization theorem.

Comment: What [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_manifold) calls the "Prüfer surface" is not separable, but t[he paper of Calabi and Rosenlicht](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1953-004-03/S0002-9939-1953-0058293-X/) mentioned in the answer on MO describes a variant of it which is separable (the surface they call "$S$" on page 337).

Comment: @Eric: Thanks; I didn’t check.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why they can't be Lindelöf?

Comment: @Doug: If a manifold admits an exhaustion by compact sets, it is automatically second-countable (each compact set is covered by finitely many charts, so countably many charts cover the whole space; now just take a countable basis in each chart), so all the usual theory of second-countable manifolds applies (e.g., they are paracompact, metrizable, etc.).

Comment: @Eric: Thanks; I knew that I’d had something in mind and should have waited until I was actually awake. Finally fixed, I think.

Comment: @Brian:  This may have been obvious to you in your answer, but I would like to add that the Uryson metrization theorem requires the space to be Hausdorff second-countable regular, and any topological manifold is (completely) regular since it is locally compact Hausdorff.